# how to remove space between to tab-layout. inside view-pager

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I want to remove space between tabs. I use custom tab layout. please check the image for clear understanding.  I  already tried app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"              app:tabPaddingStart="0dp", but not working.

[image]

```
 <CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tabs_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="0dp" />
    </CustomViewPager>
```

Comment: Do you want to pack and center the tabs?

Comment: TabLayout scrollable so I don't want any space between tab. just show image one after one. if i use app:tabMode fixed then there are no space. but i need scrollable tab

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. This code will help you.

```
final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources() .getDisplayMetrics());
viewPager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);
```

Comment: Thanks For your replay but not happen anything using this code

Answer (score 0):

Try to make `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to the child view of your TabLayout

Answer (score 0):

you can set margin between pages of viewpager using

```
viewPager.setPageMargin(int marginPixels);
```

and apply margin in negative value to reduce margin between pages